# Remove part of a text in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to remove `tel:` from a phone number in jQuery.

```
var tel = "tel:1 418 789 0283";
```

I have actually:

```
var tel = $(data).find("a.phone").attr('href');
```

How to do that please ?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? This seems to be a pretty basic task.

Comment: come on, do a little research , this is trivial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `replace` can do the trick

```
var tel = "tel:1 418 789 0283";
tel = tel.replace("tel:", "").trim();

alert(tel); //1 418 789 0283
```

Note: `trim` is used just in case you have one or many spaces between `tel:` and the phone number

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at JavaScript's string manipulation methods, e.g. substr:

```
var tel = "tel:1 418 789 0283";
alert(tel.substr(4));
```